# merge multiple rows into one column using SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata

I have a simple table in a Teradata database that contains two columns `comment_date, comment_text`. a sample data will look like:

```
comment date comment_text
9/8/2015     Hello World
9/8/2015     Some Comment
9/9/2015     New Comment
```

I want to make a select statement on this table to retrieve data in the following format:

```
    User_Comments
    9/8/2015 Hello World Some Comment
    --- new row ---
    9/9/2015 New Comment
```

So that a single column will be returned containing the comment_date column and all the comments written at this date concatenated to it.

Comment: My guess is you also want an `order id`, or `group id.` with that result? other wise you will have that in any random order rdbms want.

Comment: What mean `--- new row --` ?? are the 4 previous rows a single row?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, Concatenated together into single cell

Comment: Then you should edit it to show is a single string.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Teradata, it's on the tags

Comment: I found this for you, hope that help http://thesimpleprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/02/concat-rows-as-single-column-in-teradata.html

Comment: In other RDBMS's you would use String Aggregation functions. Unfortunately, Teradata lacks a nice simple function for this, so the recursive example that @JuanCarlosOropeza posted is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check if XML-Services are installed on your system:

```
SELECT comment_date, XMLAGG(comment_text) (varchar(10000))
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1
```

Modify the `(varchar(10000))` cast to match your data, without the cast `XMLAG` returns a CLOB.